# Gulp, es6, наследование

Tags: javascript, gulp

эксперимента ради пытаюсь переписать сборщик с использованием классов.
Хочу разделить Dev и Dist сборку в разные классы и наследовать общие модули и методы от главного класса.

Имеется следующий код.

```
class Collector {
    constructor() {
        this.gulp = require('gulp');
    }
}

class DevCollector extends Collector {
    constructor() {
        super(gulp);
    }

    buildSass() {
        return this.gulp // Почему undefined? 
            .src(this.path.dev.sass)
            .pipe(this.sass())
            .pipe(this.gulp.dest(this.path.dist.css))
            .pipe(this.server.stream());
    }
}
```

При попытке билда, вылазит ошибка, что GULP is no defined.
В этой строке

```
return this.gulp
```

Пытаюсь получить к нему доступ через SUPER
super(gulp) - не работает
super(this.gulp) - не работет

Как получить доступ к этому свойству родительского класса?

Comment: `constructor` в `DevCollector` не имеет смысла, его можно убрать и ничего не изменится. А покажите как вы создаёте объект класса `DevCollector` и вызываете метод `buildSass()`?

Comment: Конструктор нужен, в дальнейшем туда будут подключатся свои модули.
@sneas Весь код тут: https://jsfiddle.net/vearo/0m18aLjw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции `buildSass`, `buildJs` и `moveImg` теряют контекст при передачи 
в галп таким способом:

`const build = this.gulp.parallel(this.buildSass, this.buildJs, this.moveImg);`

Это можно решить вот так:

`const build = this.gulp.parallel(this.buildSass.bind(this), this.buildJs.bind(this), this.moveImg.bind(this));`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Почему то теперь ругается на метод Watch, а именно TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined

Comment: Использовал способ через bind

Comment: Понял в чем ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, помогли

Comment: молодец что разобрались с watch

Comment: а не подскажете, почему через стрелочные функции выскакивает SyntaxError, ругается на знак равенства buildSass =

Comment: Ох сорян, это не в спецификации es6. Так не будет работать. Делаю так в реакте, но там используется специальный плагин для бабела чтоб оно работало. Сейчас поправлю ответ.